# How can I specify boolean (true/false) options for TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm using:

```
$ tsc --version
Version 2.0.8
```

and trying to pass `--experimentalDecorators` [option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to `tsc` like this:

```
$ tsc --experimentalDecorators true greeter.ts
//error TS6053: File 'true.ts' not found.
```

and like this

```
$ tsc greeter.ts --experimentalDecorators true
//error TS6053: File 'true.ts' not found.
```

and like this

```
$ tsc greeter.ts --experimentalDecorators=true
// error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'experimentaldecorators=true'.
```

but no luck. What's the correct way to pass options to `tsc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean flags are false by default so you don't need to specify a value along with the flag. You only need to include the flag when you want to change it from false to true.

Remove `true`:

```
tsc --experimentalDecorators greeter.ts
```

For compiler options that expect a string, the value immediately following the argument specifies the argument's value. For example:

```
tsc --module system greeter.ts
```

For compiler options that expect an array of strings, the individual string values should be separated by commas:

```
tsc --lib es5,es6 greeter.ts
```

The compiler assumes the value passed in is a filename if the value does not match an argument name or is not in the place of an expected argument value.

Comment: yeah, it's working, thanks. But if `experimentalDecorators` was `true` by default, how do I specify `false` then?

Comment: @Maximus it's false by default along with every other flag, so including it will change the value from false to true.

Comment: thanks,what about options with string values, like `tsc --experimentalDecorators --module="system" greeter`? this gives an error: `Unknown compiler option 'module=system'.`

Comment: @Maximus try `--module system`. I can understand why that documentation is confusing.

Comment: yeah, that's working... confusing indeed. Thanks. Can you please elaborate in your answer on the general approach of passing options. For example, how `tsc` distinguishes between files and options here `tsc --experimentalDecorators --module system greeter`?

Comment: The commandline parser knows which flags require arguments and which don't

Comment: I'll add that in TypeScript 2.1, we will allow explicit `true` and `false` values for boolean flags.

Comment: @DavidSherret, consider adding information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753877/2545680)

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the compiler allows [passing in explicit boolean values](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10967).

There is a strong use case for passing in explicit boolean values to the compiler, when you are compiling against a `tsconfig.json` and want to override a specific value for the purposes of the current compiler run.

In this case, imagine if your `tsconfig.json` sets `experimentalDecorators` to false, and you want to test the compilation when it is `true` without changing the project itself:

```
tsc --experimentalDecorators true greeter.ts
```

Comment: this is correct answer, i had to deal with same situation when i have something defined in `tsconfig.json` file but want to overwrite only 1 setting via cmd args.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `false` to flags.

```
tsc --noEmit false
```